# How do i create multiple objects for child classes using parent class constructor(super())?

Tags: java

```
class Noodle {

double lengthInCentimeters;
double widthInCentimeters;
String shape;
String ingredients;
String texture = "brittle";

Noodle(double lenInCent, double wthInCent, String shp, String ingr) {
 
 this.lengthInCentimeters = lenInCent;
 this.widthInCentimeters = wthInCent;
 this.shape = shp;
 this.ingredients = ingr;
 
}

public void cook() {
 
 this.texture = "cooked";
 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
 Pho phoChay = new Pho();
 System.out.println(phoChay.shape);
 
 }
}
class Pho extends Noodle {
Pho(){
 super(30.0,0.64,"flat","rice flour");
}
}
```

I want to create one more Pho object with different parameters how do I do it?
for eg

A lengthInCentimeters of 20.0.

A widthInCentimeters of 0.85

A shape of "inflated

ingredients of "wheat flour"

Comment: Well, your `Pho` constructor does not take parameters, so you cannot do that with simply calling the constructor. You could do several things: 1) create a constructor with all those parameters and then call it with the appropriate arguments; or 2) reassign them (e.g. `phoChay.shape = "inflated"`); or 3) use a method which mutates the field (e.g. `phoChay.setShape("inflated")`).

Answer (score 2):

Just create required args constructor matching super:

```
public class Pho extends Noodle{

    public Pho(double lenInCent, double wthInCent, String shp, String ingr) {
        super(lenInCent, wthInCent, shp, ingr);
    }
}
```

So you can create all kinds of noodles you need:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Noodle pho = new Pho(30.0,0.64,"flat","rice flour");
        Noodle anotherPho = new Pho(11.0,0.33,"round","bone flour");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Extend the `Noodle` class, have a no parameter constructor in the child class that calls the parent `super` constructor with the desired parameters.

Here is some sample code:

```java
class Pho extends Noodle
{
    public Pho()
    {
        super(20.0, .85, "inflated", "wheat flour");
    }
}
```